# NoMethodError: undefined method `in_time_zone' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, insert

I am trying to insert data into my TimeSlot table. Overtime I run the code, I get this error "NoMethodError: undefined method `in_time_zone' for nil:NilClass"

Here is the code for inserting data:

```
 starts_at= begin_date
 time_slot=TimeSlot.create( starts_at: '',
                                  length: 15,
                                  provider_id: '',
                                  practice_location_id: '',
                                  practice_id: '',
                                  day_of_the_week: ' ',
                                  timezone: "Central Time (US & Canada)",
                                  hour_of_the_day: 1,
                                  health_post_id: time_slot_start_health_post_id,
                                  deleted_at: 'NULL',
                                   health_post_url: url,
                                  cached_reason_for_visits_list: "8~Allergic Asthma|9~Allergic Cough|10~Allergic Eye Problems|7~Allergy Consultation|5~Discharge (ER) Follow Up Visit|6~Discharge (Hospital) Follow Up Visit|11~Drug Allergy|12~Eczema|3~Follow Up – Established Patient|13~Food Intolerance|2~General Consultation|14~Hay Fever|15~Hives|1~New Patient|16~Poison Ivy|4~Sick Visit – Established Patient|17~Skin Rashes",
                                  type_of_patient: "any_test")
```

Here is the function for time_zone in the model

```
   def local_starts_at
     set_timezone unless self.timezone

     @local_starts_at ||= self.starts_at.in_time_zone(self.timezone)
   end
```

Please help.

Comment: "undefined method for nil:NilClass" is equivalent to NPE(null pointer exception) in java, in short `starts_at` here `@local_starts_at ||= self.starts_at.in_time_zone(self.timezone)` is nil

Comment: what is the solution according to you?

Comment: without more code, I can't tell, where are you calling `local_starts_at` and where are you assigning `self.starts_at` ? if `starts_at = begin_date` is where it's supposed to be assigned then it should be `self.starts_at` unless starts_at is just a local variable

Comment: can you describe proper file name